# Use quoted parameter as variable name for closure instantiation?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rlang, tidyeval

I've written most of my question as comments in my provided reprex. I'm looking to improve the semantics of my code and answer a specific question regarding quoted variables as parameters to closure-like functions.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# A df of file-paths split so all basenames
# are in the same column, but parent-dirs
# are spread across an abritary number of columns
# and filled with NA's.
dat <- tibble(
  ref01 = rep("analysis", 5),
  ref02 = c(NA, NA, "next", "next", "next"),
  ref03 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "last"),
  target = c("analysis.test1", "analysis.test2",
             "next.test3", "next.test4",
             "last.test5")
)

# For example this reprex df shows file-paths
# from a file-tree that looks like:
# analysis
# ├── next
# │   ├── last
# │   │   └── last.test5
# │   ├── next.test3
# │   └── next.test4
# ├── analysis.test1
# └── analysis.test2
dat
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   ref01    ref02 ref03 target        
#>   <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>         
#> 1 analysis <NA>  <NA>  analysis.test1
#> 2 analysis <NA>  <NA>  analysis.test2
#> 3 analysis next  <NA>  next.test3    
#> 4 analysis next  <NA>  next.test4    
#> 5 analysis next  last  last.test5
```

This function cleans up the 'target' test basenames.
All test-names are preceded by its' parent-dir name and a period.
(e.g. 'last.test5')

This function takes a "target" column and an arbitrary number of 
parent-dir columns. It reverses the list of parent-dirs and 
finds the first non-NA value. It then matches that value to 
the target value and removes it.

My question lies within this function:

1. Is there a more semantic way of building this function
   so that it can be expressed inside of a `mutate()' function?
2. Currently, the `replace_pattern()` function relies on 
   the fact that the `.key` column is titled "target" and
   is hardcoded as an input parameter.

   This is because of the way `pmap' works by taking p-num 
   arguments from a list and matching arguments to names.

   Since I want this function to work for arbitrarily deep 
   file-paths, I need to find a way to handle varying `.key` names.

   Is there a way to quote `.key` variable so that it will be
   the name of the first parameter of the `replace_pattern()` function?

```
trim_target <- function(.tbl, .key, ...){
  key <- tidyselect::eval_select(expr(c(!!enquo(.key))), .tbl)
  loc <- tidyselect::eval_select(expr(c(...)), .tbl)

  # First param has to be "target" since that's the name
  # of the .key column.
  replace_pattern <- function(target, ...){
    args <- c(...)
    pattern <- args %>% 
      rev() %>% 
      discard(is.na) %>% 
      first() %>% 
      paste0("\\.")

    unlist(str_remove(target, pattern))
  }

  pmap(.tbl[,c(key, loc)], replace_pattern) %>% 
    unlist()
}
```

Expected Output:
This works as expected but is not scalable. 
Also in reference to question 01, I have to pass `dat` 
into the `mutate()` function-call; which I don't see typically done.

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(target = trim_target(dat, target, ref01:ref03))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   ref01    ref02 ref03 target
#>   <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 analysis <NA>  <NA>  test1 
#> 2 analysis <NA>  <NA>  test2 
#> 3 analysis next  <NA>  test3 
#> 4 analysis next  <NA>  test4 
#> 5 analysis next  last  test5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering Question 1**

When you say that you typically don't see `dat` passed to `mutate()`, that's because most functions usually do not require a data frame context. For example, when you see

```
mtcars %>% mutate( cyl = sqrt(cyl) )
```

the function `sqrt()` works directly with the values passed to it without any care about where those values came from. In your case, you need the data frame context to help resolve the `ref01:ref03` expression. For this reason, the more appropriate pattern would be to put the `mutate()` operation **inside** your function and have it return the resulting data frame instead.

**Answering Question 2**

`pmap()` only matches argument names if the input is a named list. If the list is unnamed, the matching is done by position. So, you can either 1) unname the argument list:

```
.tbl[,c(key, loc)] %>% as.list() %>% unname %>% pmap_chr(replace_pattern)
```

or 2) since you are already subsetting your columns with `[`, turn that into a proper `select` pattern and rename the selected column accordingly:

```
.tbl %>% select( target={{.key}}, ... ) %>% pmap_chr( replace_pattern )
```

**Putting it all together**

With the two points in mind, this is how I would rewrite your function:

```
mutate_target <- function(.tbl, .key, ...){

  # No change from the OP
  replace_pattern <- function(target, ...){
    args <- c(...)
    pattern <- args %>%
      rev() %>%
      discard(is.na) %>%
      first() %>%
      paste0("\\.")

    unlist(str_remove(target, pattern))
  }

  result <- .tbl %>% select( target={{.key}}, ... ) %>% pmap_chr( replace_pattern )
  .tbl %>% mutate( {{.key}} := result )
}
```

Note that I took out your explicit `eval_select()` calls. You can pass the `...` dots to dplyr verbs directly, while using curly-curly ( `{{`, which is shorthand for `!!enquo` ) for singular columns. Here's how you would use the new function:

```
dat %>% mutate_target( target, ref01:ref03 )                           # Works
dat %>% rename( abc = target ) %>% mutate_target( abc, ref01:ref03 )   # Also works
```